# How do we initialize a "base_link" frame

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, frames, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When we run roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch, and look at rosrun tf viewframes, we get many frames which includes "base_link". Now I am trying a new setup that does not include the turtlebot. I need "base_link" for a node called Laser_geometry otherwise I will have the following error:

"base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

ROS newb here, any help will be appreciated. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298768/how-do-we-initialize-a-%22base_link%22-frame/) by [Kolohe113](https://answers.ros.org/users/36311/kolohe113/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-26**:
I suggest going through the [urdf](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) and [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials) tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do a couple things. You can make a node and use the TF broadcaster in order to create and display information about the frame.

Alternatively, you can generate a custom URDF file of your robot and specify the frames you need. Then, use the robot state publisher node to load the URDF and it will create the frames in TF for you.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1